# SSL handshake fails with java.net.SocketException on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, ssl, war

Inside Grails web app hosted on Tomcat 7 as WAR file I have web service client which fails on SSL hand shake with exception:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
```

For some reason running app in dev/test environment directly from Grails using 'run-app' command all works fine.

I enabled SSL logging on Tomcat 7 using Java property `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and we got this error:

```
http-bio-8080-exec-6, Exception while waiting for close java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
http-bio-8080-exec-6, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

What is difference between Grails dev and Tomcat environment?

We are using Tomcat 7 and Java 7, but tested with same result on Tomcat 8 and Java 8.
Target web service and its server is 3rd party, so I have no control over it.

Final part of SSL handshake log:

```
    *** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
*** Certificate chain
***
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 269
0000: 0B 00 00 03 00 00 00 10   00 01 02 01 00 AD 3E 77  ..............>w
0010: 84 C1 68 E3 C1 D7 14 54   57 C0 50 52 9E 77 3B EC  ..h....TW.PR.w;.
0020: 4A A3 E7 D4 80 3F D6 E8   BE B4 7A EF 9F E5 5C C4  J....?....z...\.
0030: 61 29 3A AC A1 99 04 35   6C E0 0D ED 3D A7 01 38  a):....5l...=..8
0040: 91 90 60 2A 44 C1 32 4F   DF C2 F0 5D E3 59 D7 EB  ..`*D.2O...].Y..
0050: 47 9E EE E6 9C 1C B8 9B   DC 1D 31 37 3C AD F4 9C  G.........17<...
0060: 4A 39 A8 FE AF DB D6 9E   83 74 77 D8 CD 74 95 71  J9.......tw..t.q
0070: 62 2B 29 94 E4 60 CE B5   E9 C2 17 62 1F 8B 7B 37  b+)..`.....b...7
0080: E0 D1 79 7F 06 69 59 97   A4 75 89 3E B0 49 1F 0A  ..y..iY..u.>.I..
0090: 8B F6 3A FF 5F E9 E1 05   F0 B3 E5 48 4F 88 AE 38  ..:._......HO..8
00A0: 4F 51 1C 14 62 5E 4B 40   DF 2D 5A 2A F4 97 A8 29  OQ..b^K@.-Z*...)
00B0: 5C 0E 9C 5F 9A FF 18 BF   07 8D 69 1B 7D 72 5E D4  \.._......i..r^.
00C0: BD EE A3 87 DA 0A 1D C3   99 18 7E 36 07 2A 5B 5D  ...........6.*[]
00D0: 61 1B 4D 9B B9 57 4A 04   0E 99 35 8E 6C 21 C2 18  a.M..WJ...5.l!..
00E0: 44 D1 B7 4E 9C CE 03 9C   C9 65 2D 43 95 B2 44 27  D..N.....e-C..D'
00F0: D4 21 49 46 06 B4 05 CE   48 83 79 F1 DF 45 29 01  .!IF....H.y..E).
0100: AA 3D 62 97 DA E8 85 3B   4A 2A AE 2E AB           .=b....;J*...
http-bio-8080-exec-6, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 269
[Raw write]: length = 274
0000: 16 03 01 01 0D 0B 00 00   03 00 00 00 10 00 01 02  ................
0010: 01 00 AD 3E 77 84 C1 68   E3 C1 D7 14 54 57 C0 50  ...>w..h....TW.P
0020: 52 9E 77 3B EC 4A A3 E7   D4 80 3F D6 E8 BE B4 7A  R.w;.J....?....z
0030: EF 9F E5 5C C4 61 29 3A   AC A1 99 04 35 6C E0 0D  ...\.a):....5l..
0040: ED 3D A7 01 38 91 90 60   2A 44 C1 32 4F DF C2 F0  .=..8..`*D.2O...
0050: 5D E3 59 D7 EB 47 9E EE   E6 9C 1C B8 9B DC 1D 31  ].Y..G.........1
0060: 37 3C AD F4 9C 4A 39 A8   FE AF DB D6 9E 83 74 77  7<...J9.......tw
0070: D8 CD 74 95 71 62 2B 29   94 E4 60 CE B5 E9 C2 17  ..t.qb+)..`.....
0080: 62 1F 8B 7B 37 E0 D1 79   7F 06 69 59 97 A4 75 89  b...7..y..iY..u.
0090: 3E B0 49 1F 0A 8B F6 3A   FF 5F E9 E1 05 F0 B3 E5  >.I....:._......
00A0: 48 4F 88 AE 38 4F 51 1C   14 62 5E 4B 40 DF 2D 5A  HO..8OQ..b^K@.-Z
00B0: 2A F4 97 A8 29 5C 0E 9C   5F 9A FF 18 BF 07 8D 69  *...)\.._......i
00C0: 1B 7D 72 5E D4 BD EE A3   87 DA 0A 1D C3 99 18 7E  ..r^............
00D0: 36 07 2A 5B 5D 61 1B 4D   9B B9 57 4A 04 0E 99 35  6.*[]a.M..WJ...5
00E0: 8E 6C 21 C2 18 44 D1 B7   4E 9C CE 03 9C C9 65 2D  .l!..D..N.....e-
00F0: 43 95 B2 44 27 D4 21 49   46 06 B4 05 CE 48 83 79  C..D'.!IF....H.y
0100: F1 DF 45 29 01 AA 3D 62   97 DA E8 85 3B 4A 2A AE  ..E)..=b....;J*.
0110: 2E AB                                              ..
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 01 8E 4C 97 8B D1 36   EB 9B A4 59 97 AC F9 75  ...L...6...Y...u
0010: 1F 3B 14 2A 7C B0 D1 FE   B8 15 DE 61 93 A7 84 AC  .;.*.......a....
0020: 5C 34 4D 4E 0D C1 19 FC   3F 42 38 77 4D FF 20 29  \4MN....?B8wM. )
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 55 3F 44 E3 2E 6E E7 A7   E1 19 9A 48 6E 14 B6 95  U?D..n.....Hn...
0010: C7 65 26 2B EB DE D8 44   C0 E1 70 68 56 AE 51 4D  .e&+...D..phV.QM
Server Nonce:
0000: 55 3F 44 E3 49 7C 29 23   32 9A 89 7B DC 7B C5 9E  U?D.I.)#2.......
0010: 26 2F FD A4 54 C4 8C C7   BD 9A 63 7E CE 7A 4E A1  &/..T.....c..zN.
Master Secret:
0000: 8E 77 FC 93 F7 7F A7 F8   4E B0 7F 46 91 0A D1 45  .w......N..F...E
0010: 21 6E 20 F0 F9 44 EB D4   06 64 7C 2D 4B 49 6F 0F  !n ..D...d.-KIo.
0020: E1 B7 93 2A 86 A8 7E CA   3E 7B 36 04 57 1E 3A 78  ...*....>.6.W.:x
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: 41 C8 49 3F 72 76 9B 54   CF 10 6C 84 39 FE BC F5  A.I?rv.T..l.9...
0010: 20 39 79 4C                                         9yL
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: 6B 57 51 ED 32 16 FE F4   17 3E 31 1B BE 03 40 8D  kWQ.2....>1...@.
0010: 6C 1F 1D F2                                        l...
Client write key:
0000: 60 72 62 0D DA B4 CC 3F   71 67 63 2B 3F BB AA A1  `rb....?qgc+?...
Server write key:
0000: 08 AE 2D DB EB E0 55 76   D7 F0 04 C2 AC E9 BD C5  ..-...Uv........
Client write IV:
0000: F8 44 FE 6D 70 61 AC 60   DF 21 A6 50 B4 44 A4 87  .D.mpa.`.!.P.D..
Server write IV:
0000: 03 BB E4 FB 9E 36 A3 DC   C7 EB D7 FA 5F 34 43 6D  .....6......_4Cm
http-bio-8080-exec-6, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw write]: length = 6
0000: 14 03 01 00 01 01                                  ......
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 156, 173, 59, 98, 213, 148, 56, 129, 171, 102, 102, 28 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 9C AD 3B 62   D5 94 38 81 AB 66 66 1C  ......;b..8..ff.
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 48
0000: 14 00 00 0C 9C AD 3B 62   D5 94 38 81 AB 66 66 1C  ......;b..8..ff.
0010: EB B3 42 ED E3 DD A9 48   07 A2 FC A8 15 EE 34 AE  ..B....H......4.
0020: D1 B7 C2 75 0B 0B 0B 0B   0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B  ...u............
http-bio-8080-exec-6, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
http-bio-8080-exec-6, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 1
http-bio-8080-exec-6, Exception while waiting for close java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
http-bio-8080-exec-6, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
http-bio-8080-exec-6, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 32
0000: 02 0A C4 92 83 43 07 2C   4F BB BB AD 4A 23 54 64  .....C.,O...J#Td
0010: 6D A5 68 33 F0 B9 09 09   09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09  m.h3............
http-bio-8080-exec-6, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32
http-bio-8080-exec-6, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
http-bio-8080-exec-6, called closeSocket()
http-bio-8080-exec-6, called close()
http-bio-8080-exec-6, called closeInternal(true)
```

**After more investigation:** I found dirty hack where I deleted 'META-INF\services\javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider' file from 'cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws.jar'. This jar dependency/plugin is forcing SSL implementation to 'org.apache.cxf.jaxws22.spi.ProviderImpl' instead of default 'com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl'. Using default implementation all works fine, but still would like to know proper fix?

It looks like that 'org.apache.cxf.jaxws22.spi.ProviderImpl' implementation sends certificate to server, but not including certificate chain, so than server refuses to accept our certificate, but why?

Comment: Probably you dont have the ssl certificate of remote party in your trust store used by tomcat !

Comment: But before `ServerHelloDone` in `ServerHello` section of SSL log it says:  `*** Found trusted certificate: [[Version: V3 Subject: CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5....`.
So cert should be fine, right?